# How do I call a controller function in a module?

Tags: 8

I am trying to access a static method of a controller class from a module, but my code doesn't work.

This is the controller class.

```
namespace Drupal\content_statistics\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class ContentStatisticsCount extends ControllerBase {

  public static contentStatisticsCount() {
    $value = $this->t('hi');
    return $value;
  }

}
```

This is the module code.

```
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\content_statistics\Controller;

/**
 * Implements hook_node_view().
 */ 
function content_statistics_node_view($node, $display, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  $value = ContentStatisticsCount::contentStatisticsCount();
  print_r($value);
  die;
}
```

This is giving me the following PHP error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ContentStatisticsCount' not found in /home/qbuser/Projects/test/modules/custom/content_statistics/content_statistics.module on line 15

Comment: Drupal\content_statistics\Controller\ContentStatisticsCount::contentStatisticsCount(); also if it is a static method, don' use $this in it(even if t() is from a trait).

Comment: You don't import full namespaces in PHP, rather specific classes/functions/etc. So: `use Drupal\content_statistics\Controller;` needs to be `use Drupal\content_statistics\Controller\ContentStatisticsCount`;

Comment: On a slightly different note; using a method like this in a _controller_ class seems like a bit of a code smell.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to define a controller, then don't use a static method:

```
namespace Drupal\content_statistics\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class ContentStatisticsController extends ControllerBase {

  public function count() {
    $value = $this->t('hi');
    return $value;
  }

}
```

The use statement should import the class, not the namespace. But this is not the only problem.

If you want to use a controller class in a hook, create an instance of the controller and use the method of that instance:

```
use Drupal\content_statistics\Controller\ContentStatisticsController

$statistics = new ContentStatisticsController;
$value = $statistics->count();
```

Your class and method had the same name, I split the name in a controller class name and the method count().

Comment: The OP's problem is getting the error about the class not being found. it could be unappropriated to add a static method to a controller, but that is not causing the error the OP sees.

Comment: $this->t() will not work in a static method, this should then be static too. But why use the controller base class in first place, when it is used only for a static method?

Comment: I agree the code shown by the OP doesn't make sense. The answer should first answer about the error the OP gets, and then point out what else is wrong in the code shown by the OP, including the fact a controller should not be used as helper class for static methods only.

Comment: I edited the answer to address all problems to get a working solution.

Comment: What if our controller uses the __construct method to pass in various other services as EntityTypeManager/ConfigFactory/etc, treating the controller as a class and instantiating with $my_controller = new Controller,  will throw an error.

Comment: @lordZ3d, for more advanced cases see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/245735/how-to-render-content-generated-by-controller-in-custom-block